# Angular Directive Best Practices - Is not using directive in Markup a good idea?

Tags: angularjs

I've seen some examples where a div tag has a controller defined, but the directive is not:

```
<div ng-app="contestantApp">
 <h1>Contestants</h1>
  <section ng-controller="ContestantsCtrl as ctrl">
   <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="contestant in ctrl.contestants">
       {{contestant.firstName}} {{contestant.lastName}}
     </li>
  </ul>
 <myapp-contestant-editor-form contestants="ctrl.contestants">
 </myapp-contestant-editor-form>
</div>
```

Is this bad practice implementing a controller without a directive? Are there situations this would be useful?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You can modify the scope of the directive to determine what properties it has access to from it's parent scope.

Comment: Notice this line '<div ng-app="contestantApp">'. Is that good practice or not? Why would you do this instead of making this div a directive?

Comment: [ng-app is a default angular directive that is required to bootstrap your angular application, unless you do it manually](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap). Your self-made, custom directives are defined within your angular module/app, so I'm not sure what you're asking still. Are you wondering about the tradeoffs between a controller vs a directive?

Comment: OK, sorry. I added the incorrect piece of code. This line here '<section ng-controller="ContestantsCtrl as ctrl">'. So the section is not a directive, but has a controller associated with it. Is that bad practice to do things like this?

Comment: btw, ng-controller is a directive and no, i won't label it as "bad".